# Case Expression error (NON- Boolean)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting error when i tried to use case statement please I'm new in SQL Query anyone know where im wrong

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'and'.

Comment: Please browse Microsoft Docs for syntax of case statement rather that posting question here. Hint:: Google `sql server case statement` and click first result.

Comment: What question are you trying to answer with your query?

Comment: Just to check the box here, if you are experiencing a T-SQL syntax error it would really help if you could post that T-SQL.  Then In SSMS when it is ran and an error generated click on that error, watch the cursor jump to the offending line, and tell us what line that is.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want (checking if all columns are true in row):

```
SELECT
  case when (
     SIGN(Orcale) * SIGN(Sqlserver) * SIGN(GeoDatabase) * SIGN(Shapefile) * 
     SIGN(Cadfile) * SIGN(Excel) *SIGN(Word) * SIGN(OtherType)) = 1 then 'u'
     ELSE 'Re'
  end
FROM tab;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d5813c5fd7c1378bf508d43baefecd2b)**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, instead of lad2025's answer where all columns are true, that you want to know if ANY column is true, this will work.

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN 
     (Oracle + Sqlserver + GeoDatabase + Shapefile + Cadfile + Excel + Word + OtherType) = 0 
      THEN 'u'
    ELSE 'Re'
  END;
```